# Arclength of Complex Exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, arc-length

The arclength for a continuously differentiable curve is given by:
$$\int|\gamma'(t)|dt=\int\gamma'(t)\overline{\gamma}'(t)dt$$

Consider $\gamma(t)=\exp(2it),t\in[0,2\pi]$

Then arclength is computed:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}2i\exp(2it)*-2i\exp(-2it)dt = 8\pi$$

But $\exp(2it)=\cos(2t)+i\sin(2t)$ so I expect to trace around the unit circle twice if $t\in[0,2\pi]$ -- giving an arclength $4\pi$.

I suspect I'm missing something obvious, but not sure what though.

Comment: I think you're missing a square root on the right of the first displayed equation.

Comment: i think you're right. -- post as answer so i can accept! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is the lack of a square root in the first displayed equation.